# Writing some nested text to a .txt file VB

Tags: vb.net

I have this code:

```
      Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\filename.txt"

            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)

            objWriter.Write(TextBox1.Text)
            objWriter.Close()
```

but I want to make something like this (note the **objWriter.Write(TextBox.Text)** in the text belowe):

```
      Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\filename.txt"

            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)

            objWriter.Write("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing objWriter.Write(TextBox1.Text). 
                             Duis dignissim, lacus vel tincidunt pellentesque, lacus ipsum venenatis libero, 
                             faucibus iaculis lectus diam id libero. Mauris interdum augue id lacus
                             commodo consequat. objWriter.Write(TextBox2.Text) et ligula sed sapien")

            objWriter.Close()
```

Update:

Actual output:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing objWriter.Write(TextBox1.Text). Duis dignissim, lacus vel tincidunt pellentesque, lacus ipsum venenatis libero, commodo consequat. TEST et ligula sed sapien

Wanted output (I would to go at head):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing objWriter.
Write(TextBox1.Text). 
Duis dignissim, lacus 
vel tincidunt pellentesque,
 lacus ipsum venenatis libero, 
commodo consequat. TEST et ligula sed sapien
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code then?

Comment: @GeoffreyR. that don't work, I get errors...

Comment: What errors do you get in which line? Edit your question to include the stacktrace(s).

Comment: He is not properly concatenating the contents of the text box into the string. See below.

Comment: And he is attempting to write a file directly into the root of C, which will require elevated priveleges. You have to run VS "as administrator" for this. Try writing the file output to your user-directory, or run vs "As Administrator" (Right-click on the VS item in your start menu, select "run as administrator").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest (but not necessarily ideal) way to do this, in your current code:

```vb
' UPDATED: Use Environment.NewLine to insert new line breaks:

Dim output As String = "" & _
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing " & _
        Environment.NewLine & _
        TextBox1.Text & " " & _
        Environment.NewLine & _
        "Duis dignissim, lacus vel tincidunt pellentesque, lacus ipsum venenatis libero, " & _
        "commodo consequat. " & _
        Environment.NewLine & _
        TextBox2.Text + " " & _
        Environment.NewLine & _
        "et ligula sed sapien"

'You are trying to write to root of C here. May require elevated privileges.
' Try writing to your user directory, or documents folder. 
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\filename.txt"
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
objWriter.Write(output)
objWriter.Close()
```

**Note that you may be running into permission problems attempting to write a file directly to the root of C drive.** I had similar issues with this code until I changed the directory path to my home folder, unless I run VS as Administrator (which your users are unlikely to be doing).

That said, you may actually be asking how to insert the contents of the textbox in  read from the streamwriter, in which case you will have to come up with some way to tind the proper insertion point. But this is how you accomplish specifically what you describe in your code above.

UPDATE:

You may want to use something like THIS to specify your output directory and file name. Or, of course, use a SaveFileDialog, and allow the user to specify.

```vb
Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
Dim FILE_NAME As String = Path & "\MyNextNewFile.txt"
```

Comment: If I want to go at head in the "output" text?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, see updated code. Not sure what you mean by "go at head." The contents of the text box(es) will be inserted wherever you concatenate them into the text string. ,&> is a string concatenation marker in VB. You use this to "glue" two strings together. the underscore <_> character is used to tell VB that the next CODE line is a continuation of the line previous.

Comment: To insert the contents of the text box, do something like "My text sentence " & TextBox1.Text & " the end of the sentence."

Comment: I have also removed the @ character from: `Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\folder\file.txt"` to run your code...

Comment: Ooh. Good catch oops. That is my C# leaking into VB. Editing post for that as well - thanks!

Comment: See updated code. You use Environment.NewLine to represent line breaks in text strings.